# SIGSEGV because of inheritance problem regarding base / derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a problem with the following code, which I derived from my actual code to create a minimal example. It contains some container class, which holds a pointer to some base class. When I create an object from the derived class (which inherits from the base class) and hand it over to a container object everything seems to work fine. But when I call a method of the container object which then calls a method from the base class where I want to perform some operations of the base classes private member (which is a map) and want to return a modified map, I get a SIGSEGV. There seems to be a problem in returning something, because the print-method works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class Base {

public:
    Base() { _m_parameters.clear(); };
    void parameters(const std::map <std::string, double> &m_parameters) { _m_parameters = m_parameters; };

    std::map <std::string, double> get() {
        std::map <std::string, double> new_map;
        for(const std::pair <const std::string, double> &p : _m_parameters)
            new_map.insert(std::make_pair(p.first, p.second));

        return new_map;
    };

    void print() {
        for(const std::pair <const std::string, double> &p : _m_parameters)
            std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << "\n";
        std::cout << "\n";
    };

private:

    std::map <std::string, double> _m_parameters;
};

class Derived : public Base {

public:
    Derived() : Base() {
        std::map <std::string, double> m_parameter;

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            std::string s_name = "param_" + std::to_string(i);
            auto p = (double) i;
            m_parameter.insert(std::make_pair(s_name, p));
        }
        Base::parameters(m_parameter);
    };
};

class Container {

public:
    Container() { _base = nullptr; };
    explicit Container(Base base) { _base = &base; };

    void do_stuff() {
        std::map <std::string, double> map;
        _base -> print();
        map = _base -> get();
        for(const std::pair <const std::string, double> &p : map)
            std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << "\n";
    }

private:
    Base *_base;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Derived derived = Derived();
    Container container = Container(derived);
    container.do_stuff();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question would be better if you indicate on which line the crash happens - you can find this out by stepping into the code line by line.

Comment: Sorry for leaving this information out, the crash happens in line 13 when trying to insert into the new map: new_map.insert(std::make_pair(p.first, p.second));

Comment: The obvious issue is here `explicit Container(Base base) { _base = &base; };`, you store pointer of local variable `base`. When ctor ends, it is dangling pointer. Why not pass pointer to base `Container (Base*)`?

Comment: *The print method works fine* is mostly down to luck, rather than correctness.  Unfortunately, one of the ways in which Undefined Behaviour manifests is by doing what you expected on your machine, right now - and failing horribly when installed and run by your customers!

Answer (score 1):

Simply running under Valgrind reveals that you're accessing memory that you freed:

```
==10852== Invalid read of size 8
==10852==    at 0x49B05B0: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==10852==    by 0x10B8FA: Base::print() (58131198.cpp:20)
==10852==    by 0x10BB66: Container::do_stuff() (58131198.cpp:52)
==10852==    by 0x10B327: main (58131198.cpp:65)
==10852==  Address 0x4d84128 is 40 bytes inside a block of size 72 free'd
==10852==    at 0x4836EAB: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10852==    by 0x10E8A5: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::deallocate(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:128)
==10852==    by 0x10E5A6: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > > >::deallocate(std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >&, std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:470)
==10852==    by 0x10DDF0: std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::_M_put_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >*) (stl_tree.h:584)
==10852==    by 0x10D17B: std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::_M_drop_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >*) (stl_tree.h:651)
==10852==    by 0x10C875: std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >*) (stl_tree.h:1915)
==10852==    by 0x10C0C1: std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::~_Rb_tree() (stl_tree.h:995)
==10852==    by 0x10B701: std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, double, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::~map() (stl_map.h:300)
==10852==    by 0x10B973: Base::~Base() (58131198.cpp:4)
==10852==    by 0x10B31B: main (58131198.cpp:64)
==10852==  Block was alloc'd at
==10852==    at 0x4835DEF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10852==    by 0x10EAF5: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:114)
==10852==    by 0x10E662: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:444)
==10852==    by 0x10DEAA: std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::_M_get_node() (stl_tree.h:580)
==10852==    by 0x10EA7F: std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >* std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::_M_create_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> const&>(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> const&) (stl_tree.h:630)
==10852==    by 0x10EC4E: std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >* std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::_Alloc_node::operator()<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> const&>(std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> const&) const (stl_tree.h:548)
==10852==    by 0x10E73B: std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >* std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::_M_clone_node<std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::_Alloc_node>(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > const*, std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::_Alloc_node&) (stl_tree.h:658)
==10852==    by 0x10E19F: std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >* std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::_M_copy<std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::_Alloc_node>(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > const*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::_Alloc_node&) (stl_tree.h:1887)
==10852==    by 0x10D784: std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >* std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::_M_copy<std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::_Alloc_node>(std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > > const&, std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::_Alloc_node&) (stl_tree.h:901)
==10852==    by 0x10CE3D: std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::_M_copy(std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > > const&) (stl_tree.h:912)
==10852==    by 0x10C440: std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::_Rb_tree(std::_Rb_tree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > > const&) (stl_tree.h:950)
==10852==    by 0x10BCCE: std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, double, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > >::map(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, double, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, double> > > const&) (stl_map.h:205)
==10852==
```

There's plenty more of these use-after-free errors, so I suggest fixing them all before further debugging.

The simple fix is to pass `base` *by reference* when constructing a `Container`:

```
explicit Container(Base& base) : _base{&base} {}
```

With that change, it's Valgrind-clean.